# Forge 3D Viewer Not Loading

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have followed the tutorials found [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels) and it is working (with smaller models).  Except when uploading a 3D .dwg file containing (11) 3D solids, the file is being rendered in the 2D viewer.  Anyway I can control this?

Note that the .dwg is AutoCAD 2015... is it possible that 2015 files are not supported in the 3D viewer?

Also... I have the opposite problem with Revit files.  3D renders properly, but I don't see how to access the 2D sheets.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your file has multiple views, Revit usually has some 3D view and multiple 2D sheet, you can specify which view you want to be Rendered in Forge Viewer. For the sample you are using, you can check the file [forgeviewer.js](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui?id=forgeviewerjs), and within the function onDocumentLoadSuccess(), the 1st parameter of the following code line actually control which view will be actually rendered by Forge Viewer, try to change to another view to see result. Hope it helps.

```
  viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);
```

Comment: Thanks... I was able to get this working.  Is there any functionality in Forge that will produce a list of views and allow me to select the one I want or is this something I will need to build via a viewer extension?

Comment: If you mean how to select views to be exported to Forge Viewer from Revit, the answer is Yes, you can go to Revit->Collaborate->Publish Settings->Select views you want as a set. The post may be a little too old, but tells the idea https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/how-to-export-multiple-3d-views-for-view-and-data-api.html